# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET app_dev.php symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I've just started to work on an existing project developped with symfony 3.

And here is the problem :

on my local environment everything is ok when i'm using app.php but something comes wrong when using app_dev.php.

I'm getting some net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors on js files. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. The files implicated are not allways the same and usually when I refresh my page there's no more error until the next one on the next page or the following one...

I'm using netbeans 8.2, windows 10 on a brandnew laptop.

I got my sources on github, my colleague is working on the same project and doesn't have this issue on her local env...

Any clue ??

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Hi Emil, thx for replying. My php log shows some php fatal error Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted in C:\wamp64\www\xmp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader.php and here is the implicated function  --> foreach ($ownInterfaces as $interface) {
            foreach (class_implements($interface) as $interface) {
                unset($ownInterfaces[$interface]);
            }
        }

Comment: And I got some "suer deprecated" php info on my dev log, related with "assetic.filter_manager"/"assetic.filter.cssrewrite"/"assetic.controller" or Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel::loadClassCache() or bundle inheritance at C:\\wamp64\\www\\xmp\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel.php:502

Comment: Which PHP version are you and your colleague using? You may compare the modules used. The issue may be caused by PHP.

Comment: symfony 3.4.1 php 7.0.23, my colleague got exactly the same and we allready checked all our modules...

Comment: Have you tried to disable OPcache?

Comment: well, opcache was not able at the beginning (as well as apcu), I thought it might be the problem, i installed both today but it does'nt work better

Comment: another weard thing : the php bin/console cache:clear command leads to a php memory failed allocation too, but when i add --no-warmup option it goes well

Comment: Have you tried to increase your memory limit?

Comment: I did, to the max. Can't be something related with this upper DebugClassLoader ?

Comment: If I disabled debug mode on dev env it goes fine, and if I able it on prod env I got the same wrong behavior

Comment: Can you confirm that this is caused by the profiler (dev toolbar)? If you disable the profiler the app works, right? Also, are you using the builtin server or IIS (or something else)?

Comment: I use wamp. And I confirm that this is only happening with the debug toolbar, evrything is fine with app.php, and evrything goes fine if i disabled it on app_dev.php

Comment: Can you try to use the Symfony's builtin server? Just to see if anything changes.

Comment: Hi Emil, it's much much better with the buitl-in server !! I just experienced 2 errors on js files during my test (nothing really anoying), and the app is really faster than with wamp.

Comment: Are there any additional errors logged in var/log/dev.log when running the builtin server?

Comment: Also are you running the project inside a container or virtual environment?

Comment: Hi Emil, sorry for the delay, some work to complete. Nothing more in the logs than the deprecated warnings I had before. But I don't have the "php fatal error : allowed memory size exhausted" anymore on the debugclassloader.php

Comment: I don't know what you mean by running my project inside a container or a virtual environment ?

Comment: Are you running the project in Docker, Vagrant or anything similar?

Comment: No, I am definitly not

Comment: Probably the best approach now is to take a look at your setup.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to too many debug notices. You should fix those and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your advices

Comment: I went throw almost all the deprecated notices (just one is remaining, something about bundle inheritance in C:\wamp64\www\xmp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel), and still have the same trouble...